# How can I debug an expo react native app that is being tested in testflight?

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight, eas

I have successfully built my first expo app with Eas and I have submitted the build to app store connect. I started testing it with internal testing using the TestFlight app. But I found a bug in my app. Now after fixing the bug what can I do? do I need to completely create a new build with Eas and then submit that to apple store connect again or is there an easy way?

Comment: Yes, that's how you would get the updated app into TestFlight.